# Can't select field without adding it to groupBy

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm trying to select field from EVENTS_TABLE but getting an error: column "events.entity_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function...
How can I select field without adding it to groupBy or apply aggregate function on it?

Any help is appreciated

There is my query

```
const builder = this.eventRepository
      .createQueryBuilder(EVENTS_TABLE)
      .select([`${EVENTS_TABLE}.type as "eventType"`])
      .addSelect(`"${EVENTS_TABLE}".entity_id`, "entityId")
      .where(`${EVENTS_TABLE}.type in (:...eventType)`, { eventType })
      .innerJoin(Entity, ENTITY_TABLE, "events.entity = entity.id")
      .leftJoin(Country, "country", "country.code = entity.country_code")
      .andWhere(`${ENTITY_TABLE}.type in (:...entityType)`, { entityType })
      .addSelect(
        `(COUNT(${ENTITY_TABLE}.id) filter (WHERE ${ENTITY_TABLE}.type = '${EntityType.VIDEO}'))::int as ${EntityType.VIDEO}`
      )
      .addSelect(
        `(COUNT(${ENTITY_TABLE}.id) filter (WHERE ${ENTITY_TABLE}.type = '${EntityType.PROFILE}'))::int as ${EntityType.PROFILE}`
      )
      .addSelect(
        `(COUNT(${ENTITY_TABLE}.id) filter (WHERE ${ENTITY_TABLE}.type = '${EntityType.COMMENT}'))::int as ${EntityType.COMMENT}`
      )

      .addSelect(`(COUNT(${ENTITY_TABLE}.id))::int as quantity`)
      // .groupBy(`${EVENTS_TABLE}.type, ${EVENTS_TABLE}.entity_id`);
      .groupBy(`${EVENTS_TABLE}.type`);
```

Comment: It is not possible.  Group by groups multiple rows.  A column that is not part of the grouping criteria will potentially have multiple values.  Hence the need to use an aggregation function.

Comment: Perhaps you really want order-by and then do your own aggregation?

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood how groupBy would work in my case and restructured my query a bit